# Convert simple emaildump to maildir or mbox format

Tags: linux, text, file-conversion, mbox, maildir

In OTRS I've got a database with emails.
I have the raw emails (in `eml` format) in a table called "article_plain".

I can easily do a dump of this using a statement like:

```
SELECT ap.body FROM article_plain ap 
INNER JOIN article a ON (a.id = ap.article_id) 
INNER JOIN ticket t ON (a.ticket_id = t.id) 
INNER JOIN queue q ON (t.queue_id = q.id) 
WHERE q.name LIKE '%something%' 
LIMIT 10;
```

Using the commandline:

```
mysql -u root otrs -pmypassword --silent --skip-column-names --raw -e 
"select ap.body from article_plain ap inner join article a on (a.id = ap.article_id) inner join ticket t on (a.ticket_id = t.id) inner join queue q on (t.queue_id = q.id) where q.name like '%something%' limit 10;" 
>> ./emlconcat_something
```

I've now exported into a single file with concatenated eml files.
This looks something like:

> X-Mimeole: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5 Received: from
>   xxxxxxxx.org.za ([10.0.50.12]) by xxxxxx.xxxxxx.org.za with
>   Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675); Tue, 28 Sep 2010 11:20:22 +0200
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/related;
>   type="multipart/alternative";
>   boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01CB5EEE.613E57EA" Received: from
>   xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.co.za ([41.208.19.106])  by xxxxxxxx.org.za with
>   SMTP; 28 Sep 2010 09:27:03 +0000 Received: from mail.dtss.co.za
>   (mail.xxxxx.co.za [196.4.89.13]) by xxxxx.xxxxxxx.co.za; Tue, 28
>   Sep 2010 11:27:00 +0200 Received: from xxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxx.org.za
>   ([172.16.252.23]) by mail.dtss.co.za with Microsoft
>   SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675); Tue, 28 Sep 2010 11:30:44 +0200 Content-Class:
>   urn:content-classes:message Subject: RE: Some subject Date:
>   Tue, 28 Sep 2010 11:24:31 +0200 Message-ID:
>   <7918418270AAB64A84F55F47027EC3135FC0F0@xxx.xxx.xxxx.org.za>
>   X-MS-Has-Attach: yes X-MS-Tnef-Correlator: Thread-Topic: Global
>   Whatever Thread-Index: ActeL4wmcWmZ5plSTzSDPA18WuxM7AAvyzQA
>   References:
>   <01BD0A17B3803A48A04E613E35E0513D4E6C54@xxxxxxxxxx.local>
>   From: "xxxx xxxxxxxx (Gauteng North, Hatfield)"
>    To: "Nellie" ,
>   "xxxxxxx xxxxxx"  CC: "xxxxx xxxxx"
>   , "xxxxx xxxxxx"
>   , "xxxxx xxxxx"
>   , "xxxx xxxxx (Centurion)"
>   , "xxxx xxxxxx (Gauteng North, Hatfield)"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>
> ------_=_NextPart_001_01CB5EEE.613E57EA Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>     boundary="----_=_NextPart_002_01CB5EEE.613E57EA"
>
> ------_=_NextPart_002_01CB5EEE.613E57EA Content-Type: text/plain;     charset="Windows-1252" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Dear Whomever

All other emails are just concatenated to the first one (as per the initial `select` statement).

**Question:**
How do I transform this into mbox or maildir format?
I.e. what script should I use on the linux server do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use [`csplit`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/csplit/)

Example:

```
csplit -z -k mail_export_file "/Mimeole/" {*}
```

The "Mimeole" part should ideally be expanded, but I suck at regex so I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Assuming that every single message starts with an `X-Mimeole:` header and that this text never occurs at beginning of line in the body of a message, a suitable regex would be `^X-Mimeole:`.  These are fairly specific assumptions which do not apply to email in general.

Answer (score 0):

The `formail` utility which ships with `procmail` has some heuristics for splitting a file into individual email messages.  The default assumes Berkeley mbox input, but there are variations for identifying ad-hoc and/or broken formats.

Since you control the generation of the dump yourself, I would suggest that you simply put a simple, unique delimiter before each dumped message instad.